# How to convert a Prisma schema into GraphQL schema?

Tags: node.js, types, graphql, prisma

With `prisma generate`, a schema file is generated containing Prisma SDL describing database model types, for example:

```
// ...
model book {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  name        String       @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt   DateTime     @default(now())
  deletedAt   DateTime?    @db.DateTime(0)
  updatedAt   DateTime?    @db.Timestamp(0)

  authorIds   String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  authors     author[]
  awardIssues awardIssue[]
  editions    edition[]
}
// ...
```

When used with GraphQL, a model type definition should be described in GraphQL SDL.

```
type Book {
  id: BigInt!
  name: String!
  createdAt: String!
  deletedAt: String
  updatedAt: String

  authorIds: String
  Authors  :   [Author]!
  AwardIssues: [AwardIssue]!
  Editions:    [Edition]!
}
```

How could I import and convert the Prisma types in a GraphQL schema, instead of code twice in both files?

Right now I manually update GraphQL schema after Prisma schema is changed, which is verbose and may cause type mismatch if either schema is different form the other one.

Comment: Did you had a look at Pothos?
https://pothos-graphql.dev/docs/plugins/prisma